# Midori won't install?

Tags: installation, midori

I've added the Midori dev. PPAs, but Midori refuses to install in both Synaptic and USC. Take a look at the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Well, I hope it's resolved, since I would like to try out the latest version of Midori. However, is anyone else having this same problem when trying to install Midori? That would confirm that it is a problem of theirs and not a problem with my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the webkit dev PPA as well.

```
ppa:webkit-team/ppa
```

Comment: Worked for me ;-)

Comment: @Icedrake: yay :D